# I got this error: "f x and y must have same first dimension but have shapes python"

Tags: python

```
import sympy as sy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = sy.symbols('x')
print("function:")
f = str(input())

#
df1 = sy.diff(f)
df2 = sy.diff(df1)
df3 = sy.diff(df2)

#Volvemos estas funciones simbolicas a numericas.
nf = sy.lambdify( x, f, "numpy")
ndf1 = sy.lambdify( x, df1, "numpy")
ndf2 = sy.lambdify( x, df2, "numpy")
ndf3 = sy.lambdify( x, df3, "numpy")

#
print("domain")
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
z = np.arange(a, b)

plt.plot(z,nf, color='purple', label='nf', marker=',')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about where you get the error and what you have tried to fix it?

Comment: The error is in the line plt.plot(). I tried changing the domain ( int, str, float) and well... nothing worked.

Comment: @BenT has already pointed out the problem, but for the next time: please include the traceback/error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are creating a function and plotting only the function call. You need to apply the function to your data so you can then plot it. So all you have to do is change your plotting line to the following.

```
plt.plot(z,nf(z), color='purple', label='nf', marker=',')
```